# Is there a variety of Yiddish where /ɛ/ can be raised to [e]?

Tags: phonology, yiddish

Is there a variety of Yiddish where /ɛ/ can be raised to [e]? If not, is it too weird to have /aj/ and /ɛ/ with no [e] or [ej] in between?

Comment: Why would it be weird to have /aj/ and /ɛ/ but no [e] and [ej]?

Comment: Examples, please. Your IPA transcription may be error-free, but without context, phonetics phlounders.